# Saving circle cropped image as JPEG format, background is not transparent in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, xamarin.android, jpeg

My requirement is, need to crop the image in circle shape and save as new image. For that, i have cropped the bitmap image using DrawRoundRect method of canvas in Android.

After cropped the image as circle and saving in PNG format, image background is transparent. But if i saved in JPEG format, image background was black. Please find my code

```
RoundedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Bitmap roundBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(roundBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.AntiAlias = true;
        RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        canvas.DrawRoundRect(rectF, bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2, paint);
         
        paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        return roundedBitmap;
    }
```

Using **canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);** not helped. I need transparent background color for JPEG format. Is it possible.?

Regards,

Bharathi.

Comment: While it *is* possible to store a 4 channel JPEG and interpret it as RGBA, this is non-standard and will not work in many applications. Also, lossy alpha is usually not a good idea. In short, if you need the transparency, use PNG. Or, if you need JPEG, store as opaque JPEG, with the transparency as a PNG. Use transparency as overlay, and compose at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

PNG support transparent background while JPG doesn't . So you could create a white image, and then paint the original onto it.

```
  public static void convertBitmapToJpg(Bitmap bitmap, string newImgpath)
    {
                  
        Bitmap outB = bitmap.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outB);
        canvas.DrawColor(Color.White);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(newImgpath);
        try
        {
            MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream();
            if (outB.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, outFile))
            {
                outFile.Flush();
                outFile.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
        {
           
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            
        }
    }
```